# MediaFileHandler: Missing file

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, dataframe, streamlit

I was running a streamlit app and I have got this error:

Does anyone know what this error is?

2023-01-20 22:13:55.890 MediaFileHandler: Missing file 382f8baf3232a7c0b8d5a750626f63dad8c1b5200d7333059676be17.png

Comment: I'm guessing that you're using an older version of Streamlit which is resulting in this error when you try to display an image. Upgrading to the most recent release of Streamlit should resolve this error.